# $\int{\cos(x)\cosh(x)+\sin(x)\sinh(x)}dx$

Tags: integration

How would I evaluate the integral:
$$I=\int{(\cos(x)\cosh(x)+\sin(x)\sinh(x)})\,dx$$
My thought was to use:
$$\cos(ix)=\cosh(x)$$
and
$$\sin(ix)=i\sinh(x)$$
or expand all four trig functions into exponentials but this was very messy

EDIT:

If I split this into two integrals where $I=I_1+I_2$
$$I_1=\int{cos(x)cosh(x)}dx$$
$$I_2=\int{sin(x)sinh(x)}dx$$

$$I_1=sin(x)cosh(x)-\int{sin(x)sinh(x)}dx$$
This second part is equal to $I_2$ so does that mean that 
$$I=sin(x)cosh(x)$$

Comment: Have you tried integration by parts?

Comment: as in split into two integrals and go from there?

Comment: Integrate by parts one of the terms. It'll become really obvious...

Comment: Expanding the integrand as exponentials isn't that messy. I tried it and got $\frac{1}{4} \left[ (1+i) (e^{x-ix} + e^{-x+ix}) + (1-i) (e^{x+ix} + e^{-x-ix}) \right]$.

Comment: While grossly inefficient here, my first move would have been to try the same as the removed comment suggested: write the integrand $\cos x\cos ix+i\sin x\sin ix$ and linearize.

Comment: didn't think it would be something so simple as IBP

Comment: Yup, you got it!

Comment: I havent really dealt with many hyperbolic functions and my knowledge of them was limited to complex numbers so it didnt occur to me to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to notice that we have $\sin x$ on right side while it's derivative i.e. $\cos x$ on left side. Also we have $\cosh x$ on left side while it's derivative i.e. $\sinh x$ on the right side.

Don't you think this seems to be much similar to what happens in the product rule.

Let $f(x)=\sin x$ and $g(x)=\cosh x$

Hence the integral can be written as $$\int (f'g +g'f) dx$$

Which simply equals $$f(x)\cdot g(x)+ C$$ by noticing the product rule.

Hence the answer to integral is $$\sin x\cosh x +C$$

You might also want to solve One such question from MIT Integration bee using similar idea which is $$\int (\sin (101x) \cdot \sin^{99}x)dx$$

Comment: Off-Topic: I found that MIT Integration Bee Integral!! https://youtu.be/qQ-56b_LvOw at 1:17:35. That was amazing!

Comment: $\int{sin(101x).sin^{99}(x)}dx=\int{sin^{99}(x).cos(x).sin(100x)+sin^{100}(x).cos(100x)}dx$ and $\int{sin^{99}(x).cos(x)}dx=\frac{sin^{100}(x)}{100}$ then use the same method as was used before where the second part of the integral $I_2$ is equal to the product of doing IBP on $I_1$

Comment: @HenryLee Or else take $f(x)=\sin^{100} x$  and $g(x)=\sin (100x)$  and continue

Comment: it is quite a nice integral though, thats why I often do the MIT integration bee integrals, and the original one was from the qualifying test: http://www.mit.edu/~same/pdf/qualifying_round_2018_test.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Hint...try differentiating $\sin x\cosh x$

Comment: (+1) for the monster hint.

Comment: Not a hint as much as just giving them the answer

Comment: My thoughts exactly

Comment: I'm actually going to downvote this.

Comment: Someone downvoted my answer. I would be interested to know why. For what it's worth, I am making the observation that the expression to be integrated is an exact derivative which one should be able to recognise.

Comment: I downvoted. I gave my reasons. There is no hint here, you just told them the answer. There's no learning process.

Comment: @Dylan actually I'm not giving the OP the answer. The OP actually has to follow the hint to find out what the answer is.

Comment: The problem is your hint *is* the answer. It does not tell OP how to arrive at the anti-derivative if he didn't know this expression, which he clearly didn't. I'm saying you need to give more subtlety with the "hint" so OP can figure it out for himself. This is too obvious.

Comment: @Dylan: I disagree that there is no learning. Trying to differentiate an ansatz (obtained from educated guess) is a quite acceptable integration technique, which is worth to know.

Comment: @Dylan I think my point is that even though **you** know what the answer is, the OP does **not** know what the answer is until he acts on the hint. In fact I'm not sure he yet knows what the answer actually is!

Comment: @YvesDaoust It would be better to tell them how to make the ansatz, rather than give them the ansatz straight away. How can you apply this knowledge without knowing all the steps?

Comment: @DavidQuinn To me it's like spoiling a movie. Once you gave this hint, it's obvious that it's going to be the answer. In the end he still wouldn't know how to go back and do the integral. All he knows is the answer to the problem. 

Anyway, he followed my hint of IBP and came to the anti-derivative, so that answers your question (of whether he knows the answer now).

Answer (score 1):

Your integrand is not exactly in a suitable form. You'd better consider the following two functions:

$$\cos x\cosh x-i\sin x\sinh x=\cos(x+ix)=\cos(1+i)x,$$
and
$$\cos x\cosh x+i\sin x\sinh x=\cos(x-ix)=\cos(1-i)x.$$

The antiderivatives are simply

$$\frac{\sin(1+i)x}{1+i},\frac{\sin(1-i)x}{1-i}$$ which you can develop in terms of the trigonometric and hyperbolic functions. Finally, take the sum of the real and imaginary parts. And laugh.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int \cos(x) \cosh(x)+\sin(x) \sinh(x)dx$$
First divide this into two integrals
$$\int \cos(x) \cosh(x)dx+\int \sin(x) \sinh(x) dx$$
Then solve for $\int \cos(x) \cosh(x)dx$ using **integration by parts** and we get,
$$\int \cos(x) \cosh(x)dx=\frac12( \cos(x) \sinh(x)+\sin(x)\cosh(x))$$
and
$$\int \sin(x) \sinh(x)dx=\frac12(\sin(x)\cosh(x)-\cos(x)\sinh(x))$$

Now add them both together and we get,
$$\int \cos(x) \cosh(x)+\sin(x) \sinh(x)dx=\frac12( \cos(x) \sinh(x)+\sin(x)\cosh(x))+\frac12(\sin(x)\cosh(x)-\cos(x)\sinh(x))$$
$$=\frac12( \cos(x) \sinh(x)+\sin(x)\cosh(x)+\sin(x)\cosh(x)-\cos(x)\sinh(x))$$
$$=\frac12(2 \sin(x)cosh(x))$$
$$\int \cos(x) \cosh(x)+\sin(x) \sinh(x)dx=\sin(x)\cosh(x)+C$$